# Как получить количество продуктов из foreign key django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть 2 класса модели и мне нужно получить количество продуктов у каждого из поставщиков

```
  class Vendor(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        seo_name = models.SlugField()
        product_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)    


    class Product(models.Model):
            vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, unique=False, blank=True, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Для конкретного поставщика так:

```
Product.objects.filter(vendor=vendor).count()
```

[Документация про count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count).

Если для всех поставщиков, то примерно так:

```
Product.objects.all().values('vendor').annotate(total=Count('vendor'))
```

`values` сгруппирует, а `Count` посчитает. [Аналогичный вопрос на английском Стековерфлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101665/django-how-to-do-select-count-group-by-and-order-by).

Comment: таким способом не получится записывать число объектов в поле в Vendor, я решил проблему сигналами, вот так: https://toster.ru/q/318583